# On Fedora, why do I have to install a devel package to get javac?

Tags: java, fedora, jdk, openjdk

From what I've heard 'JDK' stands for Java Development Kit, and on Debian based systems you install `default-jdk` to get a running `javac`.
However on Fedora (at least the recent ones) installing `java-openjdk` won't install `javac` but you have to install `java-openjdk-devel` for example.

Do I misunderstand the concept of JDK regarding `javac`? Or why does a package having a name containing 'jdk' not provide `javac` on Fedora?
I *would* understand if there was only a `java-openjdk-devel` because JDK implies 'devel' but then I don't understand what `java-openjdk` (without the devel) stands for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reflects the upstream project structure. There isn't a separate "OpenJRE" as an open source project — it's just "OpenJDK". Correspondingly, the package description for the base package is "The OpenJDK runtime environment 8", not "JRE".

Comment: So it seems to be up to the packager to "correct" this, doesn't it? On Debian/Ubuntu there _is_ a `default-jre` and a `default-jdk` package, though there is an `openjdk-*-jre` package and funnily a `openjdk-*-jdk` package as well.. Seems consistent with the versioning of Java from a logical perspective in my eyes

Comment: Well, maybe? Is it more consistent for each package follow an arbitrary scheme that seems to make logical sense to its packager, or to follow what the upstream does in each case?

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK is a name of the project that provides open-source JDK implementation. JRE is the end-user subset of it, without development tools.

`java-openjdk` is the end-user part of OpenJDK, ie. the JRE.
`java-openjdk-devel` is for developers - the whole JDK as implemented by the OpenJDK.

Comment: This is an example for very bad naming :) It's hard to find an equally bad one in my opinion..

Answer (score 0):

#### installing java-openjdk won't install javac

`java-openjdk` installs the JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

`java-openjdk-devel` installs the Java Compiler (in addition to the JRE).

> **Fedora, Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, etc.**
>
> On the command line, type:
>
> ```
> $ su -c "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk"
> ```
>
> The java-1.8.0-openjdk package contains just the Java Runtime
> Environment. If you want to develop Java programs then install the
> java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel package.

Source [OpenJDK: Download and install](https://openjdk.java.net/install/)

Comment: You stated what I've written (or did I miss something?) My question is "why". Why isn't `java-openjdk` called `java-openjre` and `java-openjdk-devel` `java-openjdk` instead? A "JDK" without `javac` is not a JDK so the name is simply wrong, isnt it?

Comment: Why (is the name wrong) is a question we cannot answer. Please go and ask the OpenJDK developers.

Comment: The not so obvious answer seems to be that the product's atomic name already contains a component which is used as a name for a subcomponent in a similar context. Like calling "Android" "AndroidSDK" instead and it's SDK "AndroidSDK-SDK"